# How to access MySQL database from Java anonymously

Tags: java, mysql

I set up mysql server on some other computer, and was able to successfully access the database remotely using this command:

```
mysql --host=server-address
```

But if I add `-uroot -p`, it would say

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'c-24-34-21-61.hsd1.ma.comcast.net' (using password: YES)
```

So I want to write a code that access the database without user id as I did it in the command line. I used below code when I used user account to access before, but I tried passing only 'url' to DriverManager.getConnection(url) to do the anonymous access.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://server-address:3306/";
String id = "root";
String pwd = "some_password";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pw);
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'c-24-34-21-61.hsd1.ma.comcast.net' (using password: NO)
```

Could you provide any insight on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please give the log when you login using the first one?

mysql --host=server-address

Comment: **So I want to write a code that access the database without user id as I did it in the command line** , what do you mean by without user id? did you mean without any username?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a user with username as "anonymous" and without password in mysql db.

And then try to access it. That would be better practice than access without username.

Comment: @Marichyasana it won't be secure if you don't have a password.

Comment: yes. It is not secure. But when we're talking about anonymous itself. We want someone to access without login,right? What we can do is , we can restrict the access privileges for this user anonymous.